# PHP Deprecated: forward() is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 2.3. in /app/bootstrap.php.cache on line

Tags: symfony

What is this all about?

What am I supposed to use instead of $this->forward()?

PHP Deprecated: forward() is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 2.3. in /app/bootstrap.php.cache on line ...

--

I'm running it in this:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{

   $httpKernel = $this->container->get('http_kernel');
   $response = $httpKernel->forward('MyBundle:Default:pageAction');

   //etc.
```

Comment: what is $this object referring to - the underlying class?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` class it looks like using the `handle()` method is the way to do it as they have deprecated the whole httpkernal class in the framework bundle:

```
public function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
    {
        $path['_controller'] = $controller;
        $subRequest = $this->container->get('request')->duplicate($query, null, $path);

        return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
    }
```

See here for deprecation changelog:

https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#220

So you could do something like:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $subRequest = $this->container->get('request')->duplicate(array(), null, array("_controller" => 'MyBundle:Default:page'));

    $response = $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 137 bytes) in /symfony2.2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 82" error

Comment: Can you try it without Action so 'MyBundle:Default:page'?  Line 82 is trying to throw a method not found exception.  I updated my answer